# Suggest a Normalization in MySql

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

I have brief experience with MySql and don't have much experience on Normalization and DeNormalization techniques

We are having a Analytics product. For each of our customer we give one JavaScript code, they put that in their web sites. If a user visit our customer site the java script code hit our server so that we store this page visit on behalf of this customer. Each customer contains unique domain name that means customer determined by the domain

we are storing this page visits in MySql table.

Following is the table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE page_visits2 (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  domain varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  guid varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  sid varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  ip binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  is_new tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  ref varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  stats_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  country char(2) DEFAULT NULL, (ISO 3166-1 alpha-2)
  region char(5) DEFAULT NULL,  (ISO-3166-2)
  city varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  city_lat_long varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY id (id)
)
```

MySql server details

It is Google cloud MySql (version is 5.6) and storage capacity is 10TB.

As of now we are having 350 million rows in our table and table size is 300 GB.

So table size is huge and even index size is also very big (approx 70 GB. I will ask regarding indexes in separate question).

For all of our Read/Write queries depend on particular domain. We don't query against multiple domains . So ***where domain = 'domain_name'*** is mandatory in all queires. Domian names doesn't change.

I want to remove redundant data from this table and want to reduce table size so that I can put whole index in memory. At same time I want better performance of the queries also. I don't want to loose query performance because of normalization. We need normalization only better performance of queries.

Couple of my approaches are

1. Using domain_id instead of domain column in above table. I will create Domains table separately (domain_name,domain_id)
2. Using address_id in place address related fields in above table. I will create Addresses table and store all address fields . (addresss_id,country,city,region,city_long_lat)

But I don't know how to exactly implement above approaches. Please tell above approaches correct or not and any other better ideas ??

My main doubt is if I create seperate table for domains for example following query

```
select count(*) from page_visits where domain ='abc';
```

I dont' know the domain_id of domain with 'abc' so that I have to call first domains table to get domain_id then need to call actual query.like that for address table also I need to call address table to get address_id and actual query.

That means for every Read/Write query I'm making two calls. am I doing any mistakes here ???

Comment: Do you have issues with the run time of your current queries, so that you want to change the data structure? Normalisation will help you to reduce the overall size of the data, but may yield an increased execution time of your queries. If you do normalisation you can still use joins in your queries, so you do not need separate query to get the domain names. There can be other ways to optimise data storage, such as partitioning. But seeing the amount of data you have and your experience in sql, you should consider taking paid professional advice based on use cases, not just on a hunch.

Comment: @Shadow Yes we have issues with run time of our current queries. That is why I'm focusing on optimizing schema of the table.

Comment: As I wrote, normalisation may yield in higher execution time, since you have to join tables. Denormalisation is actually an optimisation technique. You have to carefully analyse the use cases of your data , how a normalisation will affect the complexity of your existing queries. As I can see, you only have 2 indexes on this particular table, which are duplicate of each other. The domain field is not indexed at all, even though it is mandatory criterion in all your queries.

Comment: I'm not saying that normalisation would not help, what I'm saying is that we do not know enough to recommend an optimal solution based on facts.